Winui3: Is there any way to convert the members of a collection used as an ItemsSource
I'm trying to accomplish the same as this question asks, especialy this answer, but I'm working in winui3 (specifically I'm using the CommunityToolkit DataGrid) and that doesn't seem to have anything corresponding to WPF's ItemTemplate.  Is there any way to accomplish this?
To explain: I'm using a number of different data sources, at least one of which is data-virtualised (using this technique).  The data itself is pretty simple - just an enumerable of a structure.  But I need to do two things:

I may need to add more columns to the table, for which I need the whole enumerable;
Each item in the enumerable is shown in a cell which also contains one or more drop-downs showing some additional information, and I need to preserve the state of the drop-down in the view model. To generate that state, I need information from the column.

So, I'm thinking the best place to do these is in the DataGrid, using something like the WPF ItemTemplate

The DataGrid doesn't work like that. Can you elaborate on what kind of data you need to render? There might be another way to approach.

I reached the conclusion that what I had was two different problems.  I solved them seperately.
Firstly, adding columns to the table based on the incoming data:  I discovered there's an event that can be set up in code-behind which is called every time a new row is added.  It took a bit of fiddling to get it working, but:
public MyUserControl () {
    InitializeCOmponent();
    myTableView.LoadingRow += onLoadingRow;
    // ... other setup
}

private void onLoadingRow (object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e) {
    var item = e.Row.DataContext as MyItemType;
    if (item != null) {
        var dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue ( () => {
            // add additional columns here, if still required
        });
    }
}

It's necesary to go through the dispatcher because if you add a column while the row is being processed, an error comes from the depths of DataGridCellCollection trying to measure a column that doesn't yet exist.  You basically have to delay adding the column until after you've seen the data you have to accommodate.  But that means: beware!  If several rows are added in succession, all the column additions are queued up until later.  Before adding a column, you should check that you really need it.
Second, using column data in the data converter: When I add a column to the table, I can convert the item I've got into the type I want through a converter.  Naturally, the converter doesn't get any knowledge about which column it's in, but it is possible to add into the binding a parameter (which is given to the converter) whch provides that knowledge.  (In my case, I provided an enumerable describing the drop-downs.)  The thing is: when you add the columns you still have visibility of the whole datasource and any parameterisation of it, so by creating the binding at column-generation time, you can pass any additional context that you want.  (I have to admit, Ilearned a lot about the Binding lifecycle through this.  I also learned a lot about how hard they are to debug!)
